# Perlin Noise: A little bit of assistance needed

Tags: random, 2d, noise, perlin-noise

I read up on [this](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) article about Perlin Noise and have a few questions if anyone has the answers because I seem to be having some issues.  In the pseudo code 2D section near the bottom, it shows he randomly generates numbers but instead of one variable as a parameter in the 1D code, he now uses an 'x' and a 'y'.  Is this required in 2 dimensional noise or no?  Also, his PerlinNoise_2D Function takes 2 float parameters now instead of 1 like in the 1 dimensional example.  What are these float values supposed to be and where do they come from because I cannot find how to get them for the life of me.  So if anyone knows the answers to any of my questions, I would greatly appreciate some help.  Thanks.

EDIT: Ok simpler question, where do I get the 2 float values taken as parameters for the PerlinNoise_2D function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **2**-dimensional pattern needs **2** parameters.  Think of them as representing the Cartesian *x* and *y* coordinates of the pattern, in whatever way best fits your application.

So if, for example, you wanted to generate a W×H noise map in C++, you could do something like:

```
float noise[H][W];
for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x)
        noise[y][x] = PerlinNoise_2D(x, y);
```

You could then use the `noise` values to modulate the colour values of pixels in a bitmap, for instance.

(In this example the `x` and `y` parameters don’t need to be `float`s, but in the general case you might want them to be.)